# How to start building an ASP.NET Web API From Scratch?

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I am just getting started with ASP.NET Web API's.

While I have nothing against Templates and things like that, I prefer to at least understand exactly what is going on under the hood before just trusting the code that is generated for me.

I have had a hard time finding any sort of guide that works with building an ASP.net WEB API from scratch, without any of the scaffolding given from the MCV Web API Project Template.

So my question is: What parts of a Web API are the bare bones code for getting the API up and running?

Also , if there is a guide that I failed to find that somebody could point to me, that would be appreciated as well.

Comment: StackOverflow is for specific questions, not "where can I find" questions. Google and Bing specialize in that, and are quite good at it. Questions asking about locating things are "Shopping list" questions and are not appropriate here. There are Meta posts [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139618/172661) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/158809/172661) that explain the reasons. Voting to close as "not constructive". Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for the correction.  I will edit the question to be more specific and true to the great answer given below.

Comment: Seems like a slightly harsh bit of moderation. The question starts by asking for guidance on the code required to get started with Web API. This seems like a clear request for facts, references or expertise  - what *exactly* is required for getting Web API up and running? I for one, read the question and eagerly scrolled down for a concise answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a little bit to get you started:

1. Create a new Console Application
2. Install the "Microsoft ASP.NET Web API Self Host" NuGet package
3. Add this code to your Main method:

```cs
public static void Main()
{
    string baseAddress = "http://localhost:12345/";
    HttpSelfHostConfiguration config = new HttpSelfHostConfiguration(baseAddress);
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("Default", "api/{controller}");

    HttpSelfHostServer server = new HttpSelfHostServer(config);
    server.OpenAsync().Wait();

    Console.ReadKey();

    server.CloseAsync().Wait();
}
```

4. Create a new controller class:

```cs
public class HelloWorldController : ApiController
{
    public string Get()
    {
        return "Hello World";
    }
}
```

5. Run your application and point your favorite HTTP client to `http://localhost:12345/api/helloworld`. I'd recommend using Fiddler's composer, but a browser should work as well.

One note: This will only work in VS if you start it with admin privileges. If you're not running with admin privileges, you may need to add this line:

```cs
config.HostNameComparisonMode = HostNameComparisonMode.Exact;
```

This illustrates how to start up an HTTP server yourself in your application. Web-hosting Web API is slightly different with the major difference being that instead of creating an HttpSelfHostConfiguration object as above, you'd configure your API using the GlobalConfiguration.Configuration static.

Comment: Thanks!  My problem was that I didn't think to start with a Console Application, I had always started with a "blank ASP.NET page" template.  While I'm sure that this is possible, I like your approach to getting started much better.  Also, it allowed me to find [This guide](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/hosting-aspnet-web-api/self-host-a-web-api).

Comment: Nowadays, the easiest way to to this, using IIS hosting is by creating an empty web application and only mark Web Api.